# Dual-boot: How to access data in Windows partitions from Ubuntu apps

Tags: dual-boot, mount, hard-drive

I have finally made the move from Windows 7 to Ubuntu. But despite dabbling in Unix 20-30 years ago, I have no idea what to do now.

My Windows PC has these drives:

C: - an SSD that I repartitioned to install Ubuntu
E: - an internal HD with the volume name Data (shows as mounted as /media/keith/Data)
F: - an internal HD with the volume name Music (mounted as /media/keith/Music)

How on earth do I configure Ubuntu so that if I click on Music in Files, I see the directory on /media/keith/Music that holds the mp3 files? How do I access files in  Documents and Pictures?

So far I have tried editing .config/user-dirs.dirs (using sudo) to:

XDG_MUSIC_DIR="/media/keith/Media/Music"

but that didn't seem to work.

Also tried to create soft links from the ~/MUSIC directory:

`sudo ln -s /media/keith/MEDIA/Music` .
But again, nothing.

I feel like a complete noob (which I suppose I am really). Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Result from sudo parted -l

Model: ATA CT250BX100SSD1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 250GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End    Size    Type      File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  106MB  105MB   primary   ntfs         boot
 2      106MB   198GB  198GB   primary   ntfs
 3      198GB   250GB  52.4GB  extended
 5      198GB   250GB  52.4GB  logical   ext4

Model: ATA ST4000DM000-1F21 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 4001GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                          Flags
 1      17.4kB  134MB   134MB                Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 2      135MB   4001GB  4001GB  ntfs         Basic data partition          msftdata

Model: ATA ST2000DM008-2FR1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdc: 2000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  2000GB  2000GB  primary  ntfs

=================== FIXED!!! ===================

Thanks for your help @oldfred although I have to admit that, at first, I didn't fully understand those questions/answers. However, the reference to fstab proved to be the key. One of the things that I had been wary of was the ext4 reference. Happily another internet search, this time done with more knowledge, led me to a post on How-To Geek, which gave me a nice simple step-by-step guide as to what to do. 
First I installed ntfs-3g, then updated fstab with the following:

## Add WIndows partitions (I hope - 1st try)

UUID=54703E25703E0E6C /media/keith/Data    ntfs-3g   auto,user,rw 0 0
UUID=00240AA9240AA230 /media/keith/Media   ntfs-3g   auto,user,rw 0 0

Finally, i updated user-dirs.dirs:

XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="/media/keith/Data/Documents"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="/media/keith/Data/Photos"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="/media/keith/Media/Radio TV Film"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="/media/keith/Media/Music"

And so far, so good :-)

Again, thanks for your help

Comment: Please open a Terminal and run `sudo parted -l` then highlight the results, copy the text,, then click edit and paste the results into your question space. Please don't use Add Comment;  putting things in Add Comment loses their formatting,.

Comment: If data is in NTFS, you must make sure Windows fast start up is off.http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation And /media/$USER/XXX is a default mount by label or UUID. Better to use a mount you create and add it to fstab, so auto mounted on reboot. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk